# OleDbCommand - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I have a problem when running my code, an error occurs

> Input string was not in a correct format.

My code is:

```
protected void imgbtn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "update Companies set CompanyFName='" + txt_ComName.Text + "',CompanySName='" + txt_ShortName.Text + "',CompanyeMail='" + txt_email.Text + "',CompanyWebsite='" + txt_website.Text + "'where CompanyId='"+Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text)+"'";
       // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyId", Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text));
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.UpdateCommand = cmd;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        BindGridData();
        lblError.Font.Bold = true;
        lblError.Font.Size = 11;
        lblError.Text = "You have successfully modified the case!";
```

I don't know why this happens. Can anyone suggest to me why this might be?

Comment: Have you stepped through this code in the debugger to find out exactly which line raises the error?

Comment: actuall error on query line. when i m debugging and  in lblid=lable pass ho raha hai.

Comment: In this

`update Companies set CompanyFName='` you are missing a single quote at the start i.e. `'update Companies set CompanyFName='`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that is was this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text)
```

that was failing.

If `lblID.Text` is not actually an integer then the conversion will fail.

It would be far better to convert to an integer before hand using `TryParse` so you can recover from invalid input:

```
int localId = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(lblID.Text, out localId)
{
    // Carry on
}
else
{
    // Deal with error - this could be just accepting null input as 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like exception is raised by this code:

```
Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text)
```

Run debugger and watch the value in `lblID.Text` - if it really can be converted to `int`. Name suggest that this is `Label`, so maybe you've done a mistake and it should be (according to previous data) something like text_ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void imgbtn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "update Companies set CompanyFName='" + txt_ComName.Text + "',CompanySName='" + txt_ShortName.Text + "',CompanyeMail='" + txt_email.Text + "',CompanyWebsite='" + txt_website.Text + "'where CompanyId='"+lblID.Text+"'";
       // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyId", Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text));
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.UpdateCommand = cmd;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        BindGridData();
        lblError.Font.Bold = true;
        lblError.Font.Size = 11;
        lblError.Text = "You have successfully modified the case!";
```